# Django: AttributeError at /course/u/update-item/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data' using django

Tags: javascript, python, django, jsonresponse

I get this error when i try accessing **localhost:8000/course/u/update-item/**: "AttributeError at /update_item/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'"

NOTE: When i change `request.data` to `request.body` i get another error message that says `JSONDecodeError at /course/u/update-item/ Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

**views.py**

```
def update_item(request):
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print("Action:", action)
    print("ProductId:", productId)
    return JsonResponse("Item was added", safe=False)
```

cart.js

```
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = '/u/update-item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            }, 
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
}
```

urls.py

```
    path('u/update-item/', views.update_item, name="update-item"),
```

Comment: what if you change the line `data = json.loads(request.data)` to `data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`? does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Roham no it not still working yet, still shows the JSONDecode error

Comment: could you please add your full error trace back to your question?

Comment: Have you attempted to peek at the request object? Print your `request.data` and `request.body` to what you’re working with, etc…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSGIRequest object has no attribute 'data', In your case You have to change data attribute to [POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

data attribute is used in django rest framework. check out [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)

Comment: i chaged the data attribute to POST - it now showed this - TypeError at /course/u/update-item/
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict

Comment: POST is QueryDict so you can get productId by request.POST.get('productId'). @destiny-franks

Comment: okay, the error have been cleared, but you know i'm trying to print the 'productId' and 'action' in my cmd when i click on add to cart button, but nothing is been printed in command prompt?

Comment: can you print request.POST?

Comment: @rasulox-maxtorjon i printed request.POST and this is what showed up in the cmd None
<QueryDict: {}>
ProductId: None

Comment: your javascript updateUserOrder doesn't send data to django

Comment: yes, i noticed that, but is there something i can do?